# Open Accordion When User Lands on Page

Tags: javascript, prototype

What is the needed JS needed to make the first Accordion container to be open, using this code:

http://mibsolutionsllc.com/icontact/?page_id=7

Comment: recommend you provide the relevant code as when the referenced page changes, your question will no longer be useful to others

Comment: Hey, did one of us answer your question? If so you might want to accept one with the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#vertical-container h1:first').click();`

Assuming you are using jQuery.

or

`$('#vertical-container h1:first').addClass('accordion_toggle_active');`

might work.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code:

```
    function loadAccordions() {

        var bottomAccordion = new accordion('vertical_container');

        var nestedVerticalAccordion = new accordion('vertical_nested_container', {
          classNames : {
                toggle : 'vertical_accordion_toggle',
                toggleActive : 'vertical_accordion_toggle_active',
                content : 'vertical_accordion_content'
            }
        });

       // Open first one
        bottomAccordion.activate($$('#vertical_container .accordion_toggle')[0]);   
    }
```

the problem is VerticalNestedContainer does not existed. So bottomAccordion.activate has never been executed. You may remove that unused accordion or check if it exist before like this:

```
    function loadAccordions() {

        var bottomAccordion = new accordion('vertical_container');
        if($('vertical_nested_container')){
            var nestedVerticalAccordion = new accordion('vertical_nested_container', {
              classNames : {
                    toggle : 'vertical_accordion_toggle',
                    toggleActive : 'vertical_accordion_toggle_active',
                    content : 'vertical_accordion_content'
                }
            });
        }           
       // Open first one
        bottomAccordion.activate($$('#vertical_container .accordion_toggle')[0]);   
    }
```

or just:

```
    function loadAccordions() {

        var bottomAccordion = new accordion('vertical_container');
       // Open first one
        bottomAccordion.activate($$('#vertical_container .accordion_toggle')[0]);   
    }
```